# WHERE + NOT EXIST + 2 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query, that should return all records in T1 that not linked to records in T2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fldID, fldValue FROM T1 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT  T1.fldID, T1.fldValue
    FROM T2
    JOIN T1  ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
 )
```

But it returns empty set -- should be one record.

If I use query like this (clause on one field):

```
SELECT DISTINCT fldID FROM T1 
 WHERE fldID NOT IN
 (
  SELECT  T1.fldID
    FROM T2
   JOIN T1  ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
 )
```

It returns correct result.

But the SQL Server do not support syntax

```
WHERE ( fldID, flrValue ) NOT IN ....
```

Help me please to figure out how to compose query that will check several columns?

Thanks!

Comment: In the first query you don't need to rejoin t1 in the subquery (it would yield zero rows) Try: `WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT 1
    FROM T2
    WHERE T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
 )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [`EXCEPT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fldID, fldValue FROM T1 

EXCEPT

SELECT  T1.fldID, T1.fldValue
FROM T2
    JOIN T1  ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! And this solution is suitable for my task more than others.

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient and elegant query that will work with every database is:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
    AND T2.flrValue = T1.flrValue
WHERE T2.fldID IS NULL
```

The LEFT JOIN attempts to match using both criteria, then the WHERE clause filters the joins, and only non-joins have NULL values for the LEFT JOINed table.

This approach is IMHO pretty much the industry standard for finding non-matches. It is usually more efficient than a NOT EXIstS(), although several databases optimize a NOT EXISTS() to this query anyway.

Comment: It depends on actual data, and probably differs from case to case, but there are several articles showing `NOT EXISTS` performs better than `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` construct. [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/) [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will study this variant. But for the current task the solution from @w0lf is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Use both those columns if sub-query join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fldID, fldValue FROM T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM T2
    JOIN T1 ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
           AND T1.fldValue = T2.flrValue 
)
```

Comment: There is nothing to compare on AND T1.fldValue = T2.flrValue, tables linked by FK on  T2.fldID and T1.fldPtr fields

Comment: @YuriyVelichko - Could you edit your question to provide exact columns, few rows of sample data and expected results? You would get correct answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (I think, as I'm not sure I 100% understand your question):

```
SELECT DISTINCT fldID FROM T1 
 WHERE fldID NOT IN
 (
  SELECT  T1.fldID
    FROM T2
   JOIN T1  ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
  WHERE T2.flrValue = T1.flrValue
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same structure in both tables you can use the EXCEPT operator http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

In a more general case, you have to to use left join and find null elements in second table.

Answer (score 0):

try the below Query.

```
select DISTINCT fldID
from Table1
WHERE cast(fldID as varchar(100))+'~'+cast(flrValue as varchar) 
NOT IN (select cast(fldID as varchar(100))+'~'+cast(flrValue as varchar) from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more easy query. It returns all T1.fldID that not linked to records in T2

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.fldID
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
WHERE T2.fldID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Using IN to exclude a large number of values is terrible for performance.  Try the following:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr AND T1.fldValue = T2.fldvalue
WHERE T2.fldID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

(from my comment:) you do not have to reference t1 again in the subquery. Doing so would cause a logic of the form `select all the records from t1 that don't exist in t1 ...`, which is always empty, just like `select all blue balls that are not blue`, or `select all odd numbers that are even` ...
The first query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fldID, fldValue
FROM T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM T2
   WHERE T2.fldID = T1.fldPtr
 );
```

---

And: in your original query, the subquery is *uncorrelated*: The `t1` in the subquery *shadows* the `t1` in the main query, making the subquery not referring any table or alias from the main query: it returns either `True` (some row exists) or `False`, the result being totally uncorrelated to the rows in the main query. (yet another good reason to **use aliases** instead of real table names in your queries)